# What is Extreme Learning Machine? Why tuning of weights is not required?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, bigdata, training

The wikipedia says:

> Extreme learning machines are feedforward neural network for classification, regression,
>       clustering, sparse approximation, compression and feature learning with a single layer or 
>       multi layers of hidden nodes, where the parameters of hidden nodes (not just the weights
>       connecting inputs to hidden nodes) need not be tuned.

How is it possible to assign values to links without actually seeing the *Training set*?

Till now from my research to understand this, I've made a lead, but not satisfactory because I can't anything from this below paragraph.

> For any nonconstant piecewise continuous function
>   that is used as the activation function, if the parameters of
>   the hidden neurons are tuned, then the function can make
>   the SLFNs approximate any target continuous function f (x).
>   Then, according to any continuous distribution probability, the
>   function sequence {h subscript i (x)} where i goes from 1 to L   can be randomly generated, and
>   it has the universal approximation capability, which means that
>   $$\lim_{L→ \infty} ||L
> i=1 βi hi (x) − f (x)|| = 0$$
>   holds with probability
>   of one with appropriate output weights $β$.

SOURCE: A Parallel Multiclassification Algorithm for Big
Data Using an Extreme Learning Machine, IEEE transactions on neural networks 2017

Can anyone prove/explain this with an example please?

Also any extra knowledge on extreme learning machine is very welcomed.

Comment: This [link](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap4.html) might be helpful.

Comment: can you fix the formula in your quote? that doesn't look correct...

Answer (score 2):

ELM is actually solving a generalized linear problem :

\begin{equation}
H\beta = Y 
\end{equation}

where $H$ is the matrix of the hidden layer output, $\beta$ is the weight vector (or matrix) connecting the hidden layer and the output layer and $Y$ symbolizes the target of your training.

The goal is to find $\beta$ using the pseudo-inverse of H.

Solving this problem is equivalent of finding the $\beta$ achieving the minimum of the Least-square problem $||H\beta - T ||$ : 
\begin{equation}
\beta = \underset{\beta}{\text{min}} \left \vert\left \vert H\beta - T \right\vert\right\vert 
\end{equation}
To answer your question

> How is it possible to assign values to links without actually seeing the Training set?

Since $H$ depends on the activation functions, on the initialized weight matrix linking Input layer and hidden layer and on each hidden node bias, it encompasses all the input information and ensures a learning by tuning $\beta$ coherently.

You can find lot more details in [ELM Theory and Application](http://www.di.unito.it/~cancelli/retineu11_12/ELM-NC-2006.pdf) or in this [ELM presentation](http://www-lia.deis.unibo.it/phd/materials/courses/Reti%20Neurali%20Teoria%20e%20Applicazioni/Fariselli2/ELM-Workshop-NUS.pdf) for example.